# Ruby on Rails: Routing for subdomain and custom domain possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm looking to route users' pages from their subdomains and also their custom domains. For example, consider three domains:

```
app.com
user1.app.com
user1.com
```

A visitor should be able to see the user's page at both the subdomain from the app's domain (user1.app.com) as well as the user's custom domain (user1.com). That is, a visitor will visit the user page when visiting any subdomain of "app.com" or a root domain that is NOT "app.com".

How would I set up routes to do so?

Maybe something along the lines of this pseudo-code:

```
match "/", :to => "user_page#show", :constraints => { :subdomain => /.+/ OR :domain => NOT(app.com) }
```

What do you think?

Comment: i think that this is not a routing issue. just check the request in your rails app `request.domain` or `request.subdomain`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [a constraint utility class or module](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints).

```
module DomainConstraint
  def self.matches? request
    request.subdomain.present? || request.domain != 'app.com'
  end
end

constraints DomainConstraint do
  # routing here
end
```

if your constraint only applies to one route, you can do :

```
resources :foo, constraints: DomainConstraint
```

note : your utility class can also be replaced by a simple [lambda](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping/constraints) (see "Dynamic request matching")

Comment: accepted suggestions to edit from anonymous user. I don't know why reviewers rejected them (replaced regex `=~ /.+/` with `present?`)